# Firestore WriteBatch Fails to execute when using set(), update(), delete() on Document Reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an `Android` application using `Firestore` as my backend.  I am writing to multiple collections within a document, and in some instances can `write` to a document, `update` the document, then `delete` the document all within the same `WriteBatch`. Whenever a user creates, then later `deletes` a document within the same `WriteBatch` my application crashes.  Below is the code and error I receive.

```
private void executeBatchedWrite() {
    WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

    DocumentReference doc = notebookRef.document("123");
    batch.set(doc, new Note("New Note", "New Note", 1));

    batch.update(doc, "timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

    batch.delete(doc);

    batch.commit();
}
```

My app crashes and I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza.zzb(SourceFile:324)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzd.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Comment: Please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Is it possible to write to the same document multiple times in one batch?

Comment: @DauleDK Writing to the same document multiple times in the same batch is no problem, so long as I don't then later delete the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined this was a bug and reported it to Google.  Further testing indicates that this issue may be specific to writing FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to a document that will eventual be deleted within the same batch write. If the FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is replaced with a different value (ex: System.currentTimeMillis()), the issue seems to go away.