# Internal error in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello can help me how to fixed this. i got this problem on version Android 17

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza.zzb (SourceFile:324)
com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzd.run ()
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:800)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5469)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:857)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:624)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

> Caused by java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Only one thread may be created in an AsyncQueue.

```
com.google.a.a.a.a.zza.zza (SourceFile:2032)
com.google.a.a.a.a.zza.zza (SourceFile:2017)
com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.newThread (SourceFile:195)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init> (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:568)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:883)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:962)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run (SourceFile:190)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:838)
```

this one code

```
Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("username", userName);
users.put("email", userEmail);
users.put("idUser", idUser);

db.collection("users")
.whereEqualTo("id", idUser)
.get()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    db.collection("users").document(document.getId())
                            .update(users)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d("DocumentReference", "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.w("DocumentReference", "Error updating document", e);
                                }
                            });
                }
        } else {
            Log.d("DocumentReference", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50673476/4815718

Comment: @BobSnyder but on my class do not have FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Comment: Post the code that produces the error. A [mcve] is best.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that produces this error.

Comment: already add the code

Comment: For the time, comment the code of update and see whether the records are inserted in db or not. If yes, add the db structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "internal error" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)